# Does the people remember the comet incident?

Tags: weathering-with-you

I assume that you guys have already watch *Your Name* this fabulous movie that directed by Makoto Shinkai. Recently there's a movie which also directed by Makoto Shinkai and the movie also seems like kinda related to *Your Name*.

**HUGE SPOILER!**

> In the film *Weathering with You*, there are two character from *Your Name* appear in this film. One is **Mitsuha** another is **Taki**.

So we know that in the film *Your Name*, there is a comet piece going to crash on Earth which destroy Itomori city. So my question is does the people who live in *Weathering with You* know the comet incident?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's ever been official confirmation that those characters appearing is anything more than a cameo, so it isn't even clear whether the meteor incident occurred in Weathering With You. (As I recall, there was never a clear view of the region of Japan where it happened to show whether or not there's a crater.)

That said, if they did occur in the same universe then people would have remembered it - it was a fairly major event that destroyed an entire town - but it could well be something that has already faded from most people's minds because it wasn't a cause of many deaths.

> Since, if Mizuha is living in Tokyo, then this must take place in the timeline where they managed to bring everyone to the school before the impact.